# Do we have to check the LinkerD version compatibility while upgrading AKS version? Is there any compatibility matrix for LinkerD - K8 version?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, linkerd

I was about to upgrade my Kubernetes cluster from 1.22.x to 1.23.x, which needs me to also upgrade helm from 3.7.x to 3.8.x since 3.7.1 is not compatible with Kubernetes 1.23.x.

Currently my clusters are running with Linkerd 2.9. Is there any compatibility matrix as such for linkerd as well just like it is for helm? Like Linkerd version 2.9 doesn't support K8 versions above 1.22 etc.? I tried looking through the documentation but couldn't find anything regarding the compatibility between linkerd and K8s. Apologies if this is very trivial, new to Linkerd + K8s. :)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Linkerd documentation has the upgrade notice for each new version introduced as below: https://linkerd.io/2.13/tasks/upgrade/#upgrade-notice-stable-2-12-0.

For each linkerd version, a minimum supported k8s version is given in the official documentation.

But the documentation won't mentioned the maximum k8s version supported for a given linkerd version.

It is generally not mentioned in anywhere about the maximum version supported because when the documentation( or say the new version of linkerd) is introduced, they don't/can't know what will feature/API Kubernetes deprecates or changes in future for sure, which can have an impact on the particular version of linkerd.

Please correct me if Im wrong, but only way I know to check if an old linkerd version supports a K8s version( which is above minimum supported version for the linkerd version in question) is to deploy and see if there are any warnings while deploying :(.

Yeah it would be lot better if @Linkerd team can update their documentation with maximum supported K8s version for old linkerd versions.